# when i push my code to git ,git call this error :client_loop: ssh_packet_write_poll: Connection to xxxx: Permission denied

Tags: git, ssh

when i push my code to git ,git call this error :client_loop: ssh_packet_write_poll: Connection to xxxx: Permission denied
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet fatal: 远端意外挂断了
the pull is enable,and i try to set git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400 its unUsed.
Is anyone can help me? thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You're using ssh, not https, and the ssh connection is failing entirely. Check the URL you have for the other Git repository.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. This fixed it for me:

```
git remote update
```